# How do I toggle a full screen Swing frame out of full screen mode?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I've got code that looks something like this, which makes my JFrame fullscreen:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();

JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Title", device);
myFrame.setVisible(true);
myFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
myFrame.setResizable(false);
myFrame.validate();

device.setFullScreenWindow(myFrame);
```

How do I later get that same JFrame to stop being fullscreen and revert to being just a normal window? I don't see any opposite to the `setFullScreenWindow` method on the [GraphicsDevice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) class. I'd like to be able to toggle back and forth as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setFullScreenWindow(null);` and then call `myFrame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: Thanks so much for this. One more quick question: I just realized my application isn't actually going into full screen mode. I'm getting an `IllegalComponentStateException` saying `The frame is displayable` on the line where I call `setUndecorated(true)`. Any ideas on how to fix that code above to get it working?

Comment: It could be because of the calls to `setExtendedState()` or `myFrame.validate()`; they aren't necessary for a fullscreen window.

Comment: I did some research and the actual problem is that you set your frame as visible at the very beginning. Remove that line and your program should work fine.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I can now toggle between full screen and normal mode. However, the setUndecorated() call keeps giving me the same exception when I try to call it, which means when it comes back to "normal" window mode, I lose the framing for the window which would have the minimize/maximize/close buttons. Thanks for all your help, but I'm wondering if you also know how I can get that call to actually work? As you can see I'm accepting your answer as the correct one, but if you could go the extra mile and help me solve this one last problem that'd be awesome.

Comment: You can call setUndecorated() whenever you want, **so long as** your frame is not displayable. That means that your frame must either have never been displayed, or you must call dispose first. Take a look on pasteBin at a program I wrote: http://pastebin.com/i6bBn3K7